# Service and multi threads call

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I created service and this service has thread pool, if the service destroyed does that mean that the thread are destroyed too, how to stop running  threads if they are still working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the service destroyed does that mean that the thread are destroyed too

No. The Thread will continue to run even after the `Service` is destroyed, until OS terminates the process of your app at some point which could lead to memory leaks.

If you create the thread you have to clean it up.

> how to stop running threads if they are still working?

You should not use `stop()` to terminate the thread because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state. The cleaner way to clean up would be to interrupt the thread. You need to maintain reference to the `Thread`. Then to clean up the thread do following:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

In `run()` of your Runnable in Thread, do following

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // stop your thread
    if (interrupted()) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```